# comparison in templated function

Tags: c++

I am writing a templated function which at some point does a comparison

```
template<typename T>
void Foo(T val)
{
    .
    .
    .

    if(val != 0) // what if val is of type std::string?
    {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

this works for integer data but what if T is std::string? How should I handle that condition so that I can use both std::string and int in the function?

Comment: What does it mean for a string to be non-zero?  I ask this seriously, I can think of 40 answers, but I cannot determine which is right for your problem.

Comment: Please reconsider whether you really need templates for your purpose or not.

Comment: `val != T{}` is one possibility.

Comment: This question can't be answered. It's an XY problem, don't ask us how to compare a `std::string` to 0, tell us about your specific problem, why do you need to do such a comparison in the first place? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why does this work for integer data? What does an input of `0` mean, and why is it special?

Comment: You can specialize your template (or better overload the function) for strings and any other type than needs special behaviour. And you can perform `static_assert`, e.g. `static_assert(std::is_integral_v<T>)` before you work with the value to check whether type is valid or not.

Comment: If you're treating 0 / empty string / whatever as a special value that represents the absence of a value, maybe you should think about using `std::optional<T>` instead.

Answer (score -2):

edit: ignore everything I typed below and just use template specialization.

If you also must also account for the possibility of a string, you'll have to build another function to handle those since the comparison is different, using function overloading instead of trying to compile it in with your template that handles Integers, Floats, Doubles, and the like. You could use `.compare(anotherstring or "") == 0` `.empty()` `.length() == 0`. I would recommend reading up on all three of those standard operations if you are not familiar with them. Your string handling function would look something like this (depending on which clause best suited your case):

```
void Foo(std::string val)
{
    .
    .
    .

    if (val.length() == 0) {
        std::cout << "string is of 0 length\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "string is of " << thing.length() << " length\n";
    }


    if (val.compare("") == 0) {
        std::cout << "string is a blank string\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "string is not a blank string\n";
    }

    if (val.empty()) {
        std::cout << "string is empty\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "string is not empty\n";
    }

}
```

you could even `or` them all in one big checker that short circuits and doesn't continue checking if the first one comes back true, though this might be redundant in some cases. Something like:

```
if (val.compare("") == 0 || val.length == 0 || val.empty()) { doSomething(); }
```

hope this helps and happy coding

Comment: I believe this is the right answer (as it does quite literally work to handle the generic situation) and allow the asker to implement a solution and move on with his life.